# Unable to delete and update entry in SQLite database while selecting through list view

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

My app similar to todo application where list of todos are associated with a tag
Ex:
tag1: "Sunday"
   todo list: Task: "wake up late" info: "task1"
              Task: "break fast"   info: "task2"

tag2 : "Monday"
   todo list: Task: "wake up at 6"     info: "to early wakeup"
              Task: "Read news paper"  info: "task2"
              Task: "eat break fast"   info: "task3"

When user select a tag (say Sunday) I am making a list of todos of that tag and showing it as list view in my fragment. Each entry in list view shows Task and info details.

Now I am implementing long press on each list entry and show options "delete entry" and "update info".

For "delete" operation, I have delete the entry from database and show list updated list view.

For "update info", read input from user and update "info" details and refresh the list view.

I am able to achieve everything except database operations such as deleting respective row if user selects deletion and updating a particular row with given info.

I am taking help from 
    http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-sqlite-database-with-multiple-tables/

with some modification in names (not logic)

But some how delete and update are not working with the KEY_ID.

Below is code that create tables:

```
    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ROWDATA = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_ROWDATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ROWDATA
        + " TEXT," + KEY_INFOPATH + " TEXT," + KEY_STATUS + " INTEGER," + KEY_CREATED_AT
        + " DATETIME" + ")";

// CategoryTag table create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TAG = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_TAG
        + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TAG_NAME + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

// rowdata_tag table create statement
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
        + KEY_ROWDATA_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_TAG_ID + " INTEGER,"
        + KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" + ")";

    public static DatabaseHelper sInstance;
        public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // creating required tables
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ROWDATA);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TAG);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // on upgrade drop older tables
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ROWDATA);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TAG);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG);

    // create new tables
    onCreate(db);
}

// ------------------------ "rowdatas" table methods ----------------//

/**
 * Creating a rowdata
 */
public long createRowData(RowData rowdata, long[] tag_ids) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ROWDATA, rowdata.getPath());
    values.put(KEY_INFOPATH, rowdata.getInfoPath());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, rowdata.getStatus());
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    // insert row
    long rowdata_id = db.insert(TABLE_ROWDATA, null, values);
    Log.e(LOG, "New rowdata id for: " + rowdata.getPath() + "is: " + rowdata_id + "tag id: " + tag_ids[0] + " to table: " + TABLE_ROWDATA);

    // insert tag_ids
    for (long tag_id : tag_ids) {
        createRowDataTag(rowdata_id, tag_id);
    }

    return rowdata_id;
}

/**
 * get single rowdata
 */
public RowData getRowData(long rowdata_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA + " WHERE "
            + KEY_ID + " = " + rowdata_id;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (c != null)
        c.moveToFirst();

    RowData td = new RowData();
    td.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
    td.setPath((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWDATA))));
    td.setInfoNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INFOPATH))));
    td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
    return td;
}

/**
 * getting all rowdatas
 * */
public List<RowData> getAllRowDatas() {
    List<RowData> rowdatas = new ArrayList<RowData>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RowData td = new RowData();
            td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
            td.setPath((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWDATA))));
            td.setInfoNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INFOPATH))));
            td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));

            // adding to rowdata list
            rowdatas.add(td);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return rowdatas;
}

/**
 * getting all rowdatas under single tag
 * */
public List<RowData> getAllRowDatasByCategoryTag(String tag_name) {
    List<RowData> rowdatas = new ArrayList<RowData>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA + " td, "
            + TABLE_TAG + " tg, " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG + " tt WHERE tg."
            + KEY_TAG_NAME + " = '" + tag_name + "'" + " AND tg." + KEY_ID
            + " = " + "tt." + KEY_TAG_ID + " AND td." + KEY_ID + " = "
            + "tt." + KEY_ROWDATA_ID;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            RowData td = new RowData();
            td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
            td.setPath((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWDATA))));
            td.setInfoNote((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INFOPATH))));
            td.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));

            // adding to rowdata list
            rowdatas.add(td);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return rowdatas;
}

public RowData getRowDataId(String tag_name, RowData rowdata) {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA + " td, "
            + TABLE_TAG + " tg, " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG + " tt WHERE tg."
            + KEY_TAG_NAME + " = '" + tag_name + "'" + " AND tg." + KEY_ID
            + " = " + "tt." + KEY_TAG_ID + " AND td." + KEY_ID + " = "
            + "tt." + KEY_ROWDATA_ID;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if(rowdata.getPath().equals(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWDATA)))) {
                rowdata.setId(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID));
                rowdata.setInfoNote(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_INFOPATH)));
                rowdata.setCreatedAt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
                break;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.e(LOG, rowdata.getPath() + " got id: " + rowdata.getId());
    return rowdata;
}
/**
 * getting rowdata count
 */
public int getRowDataCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return count;
}

/**
 * Updating a rowdata
 */
public int updateRowData(RowData rowdata) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ROWDATA, rowdata.getPath());
    values.put(KEY_INFOPATH, rowdata.getInfoPath());
    values.put(KEY_STATUS, rowdata.getStatus());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_ROWDATA, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(rowdata.getId()) });
}

public int getRowDataCountByCategoryTag(String tag_name) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA + " td, "
            + TABLE_TAG + " tg, " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG + " tt WHERE tg."
            + KEY_TAG_NAME + " = '" + tag_name + "'" + " AND tg." + KEY_ID
            + " = " + "tt." + KEY_TAG_ID + " AND td." + KEY_ID + " = "
            + "tt." + KEY_ROWDATA_ID;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    return count;
}
/**
 * Deleting a rowdata
 */
public void deleteRowData(long todo_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.e(LOG, "Deleting rowdata id: " + todo_id + " from table: " + TABLE_ROWDATA);
    int ret = db.delete(TABLE_ROWDATA, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(todo_id) });

}

// ------------------------ "tags" table methods ----------------//

/**
 * Creating tag
 */
public long createCategoryTag(CategoryTag tag) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TAG_NAME, tag.getTagName());
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());

    // insert row
    long tag_id = db.insert(TABLE_TAG, null, values);

    return tag_id;
}

public String[] getAllCategoryTagNames() {
    String[] tagNames = null;
    int count = 0;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TAG;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    tagNames = new String[c.getCount()];
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            tagNames[count] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG_NAME));
            count++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return tagNames;
}
/**
 * getting all tags
 * */
public List<CategoryTag> getAllCategoryTags() {
    List<CategoryTag> tags = new ArrayList<CategoryTag>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TAG;

    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            CategoryTag t = new CategoryTag();
            t.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
            t.setTagName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG_NAME)));

            // adding to tags list
            tags.add(t);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return tags;
}

public CategoryTag getCategoryTagId(CategoryTag tag) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TAG;
    boolean found = false;
    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG_NAME)).equals(tag.getTagName())) {
                tag.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))));
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    if(found) {
        return tag;
    } else {
        tag.setId(-1);
        return tag;
    }
}

/**
 * Updating a tag
 */
public int updateCategoryTag(CategoryTag tag) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TAG_NAME, tag.getTagName());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_TAG, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(tag.getId()) });
}

/**
 * Deleting a tag
 */
public void deleteCategoryTag(CategoryTag tag, boolean should_delete_all_tag_rowdatas) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // before deleting tag
    // check if rowdatas under this tag should also be deleted
    if (should_delete_all_tag_rowdatas) {
        // get all rowdatas under this tag
        List<RowData> allTagToDos = getAllRowDatasByCategoryTag(tag.getTagName());

        // delete all rowdatas
        for (RowData rowdata : allTagToDos) {
            // delete rowdata
            deleteRowData(rowdata.getId());
        }
    }

    // now delete the tag
    db.delete(TABLE_TAG, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(tag.getId()) });
}

// ------------------------ "rowdata_tags" table methods ----------------//

/**
 * Creating rowdata_tag
 */
public long createRowDataTag(long rowdata_id, long tag_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ROWDATA_ID, rowdata_id);
    values.put(KEY_TAG_ID, tag_id);
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, getDateTime());
    Log.e(LOG, "Inserting rowdata_id: " + rowdata_id + " tag id: " + tag_id + " to table: " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG);
    long id = db.insert(TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG, null, values);
    Log.e(LOG, "inserted id: " + id);
    return id;
}

public void printRowData_Tag() {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG;
    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.e(LOG, TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG + "tag id: " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TAG_ID)) + "rowdata id: " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWDATA_ID)));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
/**
 * Updating a rowdata tag
 */
public int updateRowData_Tag(long id, long tag_id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TAG_ID, tag_id);

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
}

/**
 * Deleting a rowdata tag
 */
public void deleteRowData_Tag(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.e(LOG, "Deleting id: " + id + " from : " + TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG);
    db.delete(TABLE_ROWDATA_TAG, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
}

// closing database
public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}

/**
 * get datetime
 * */
private String getDateTime() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
}
```

I am able to create entries in TABLE_ROWDATA.
I am not able to delete entry from TABLE_ROWDATA.
Below code which calls to delete entry and update listview:

```
        public void deleteListEntry(int position) {
    CategoryTag tag = new CategoryTag(title);
    tag = db.getCategoryTagId(tag);
    RowData rowdata = new RowData(pathList[position], 0);
    List<RowData> rowdatas = db.getAllRowDatasByCategoryTag(title);
    for (RowData rd : rowdatas) {
        if (rd.getPath().equals(pathList[position])) {
            db.deleteRowData(rd.getId());
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.e("tagIt", "Count: " + db.getRowDataCountByCategoryTag(title));
}
public void updateRowDataList(){
    List<RowData> rowdatas = db.getAllRowDatasByCategoryTag(title);
    int i = 0;
    if(rowdatas.size() == 0) {
        Log.e("tagIt", "No list found ");
    }
    pathList = new String[rowdatas.size()];
    pathInfoList = new String[rowdatas.size()];
    for (RowData rowdata : rowdatas) {
        pathList[i] = rowdata.getPath();
        pathInfoList[i] = rowdata.getInfoPath();
        Log.e("tagIt", "rowdata-id: " + rowdata.getId());
        i++;
    }
}
public  View updateFragmentWithData(){
    updateRowDataList();
    lpadapter = new ListPathsAdapter(getActivity(), pathList, pathInfoList);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pathsList);
    lv.setAdapter(lpadapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            openFile(position);
            return;
        }
    });
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
    return rootView;
}


        public  void updateInfo(final int position) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Update info");
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    builder.setView(input);
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            String value = input.getText().toString();
            CategoryTag tag = new CategoryTag(value);
            List<RowData> rowdatas = db.getAllRowDatasByCategoryTag(title);
            int i = 0;
            for(RowData rd : rowdatas){
                if (i == position){
                    rd.setInfoNote(value);
                    db.updateRowData(rd);
                    break;
                }
            }
            updateFragmentWithData();
        }
    });
```

Above delete call is from below selection in onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item);. where info.position is position in the of list entries of public String[] list pathList.

```
       @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.send:
            openFile(info.position);
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            deleteListEntry(info.position);
            updateFragmentWithData();
            return true;
        case R.id.updateinfo:
            updateInfo(info.position);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am not sure where is the issue in DB. 
db.delete returns 0 But after deletion recreation of list shows same list again.

Comment: instead of that third party tutorials (in most cases incorrect), why dont you read the official material like notepad tutorial? the tutorial you use is not doing the stuff the right way...

Comment: *in most cases incorrect* especially when we are talking about androidhive

Comment: @pskink Do you know how it sounds in political correct europe ? :)